# Exportar XLS en microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript

Que tal lo que pasa es que tengo una funcionalidad para exportar mi tabla en xls , el detalle es que solo puedo exportar en el navegador chrome y en mozilla , pero en microsoft edge no sirve la funcionalidad , quisiera saber que mas necesito anexar a mi código para que este funcione en este navegador, espero que alguien me pueda orientar saludos cordiales.

```
  function tablesToExcel(idtb) {
        {
            //mandar a llamar la funcion* 
            //genTableExcel()
            var tab_text = document.getElementById(idtb);
            var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
            var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");

            if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./))      // If Internet Explorer
            {
                txtArea1.document.open("txt/html", "replace");
                txtArea1.document.write(tab_text.outerHTML);
                txtArea1.document.close();
                txtArea1.focus();
                sa = txtArea1.document.execCommand("Guardar", true, "");
            }
            else                 //other browser not tested on IE 11
            {
                var html = tab_text.outerHTML;
                while (html.indexOf('á') != -1) html = html.replace('á', '&aacute;');

                while (html.indexOf('Á') != -1) html = html.replace('Á', '&Aacute;');
                while (html.indexOf('é') != -1) html = html.replace('é', '&eacute;');
                while (html.indexOf('É') != -1) html = html.replace('É', '&Eacute;');
                while (html.indexOf('í') != -1) html = html.replace('í', '&iacute;');
                while (html.indexOf('Í') != -1) html = html.replace('Í', '&Iacute;');
                while (html.indexOf('ó') != -1) html = html.replace('ó', '&oacute;');
                while (html.indexOf('Ó') != -1) html = html.replace('Ó', '&Oacute;');
                while (html.indexOf('ú') != -1) html = html.replace('ú', '&uacute;');
                while (html.indexOf('Ú') != -1) html = html.replace('Ú', '&Uacute;');
                while (html.indexOf('º') != -1) html = html.replace('º', '&ordm;');
                while (html.indexOf('ñ') != -1) html = html.replace('ñ', '&ntilde;');
                while (html.indexOf('Ñ') != -1) html = html.replace('Ñ', '&Ntilde;');
                //var endc = encodeURIComponent(tab_text.outerHTML);
                //endc = endc.replace('%C3%B3', 'ó');
                //console.log(endc);
                sa = window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(html));
            }

            return (sa);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ves algo en la consola del navegador? Algún error?

Comment: realmente no, lo unico que hace en el edge es que abre una segunda ventana en el navegador solo es lo unico que hace